# How to make line spacing in the title different from \linespread

Tags: titles, line-spacing

I have a long title. The default spacing between the two lines is too large, because I set `\linespread{1.5}` for double spacing in the text. Is there a way to prevent my title from being affected by `\linespread`?

Below is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\linespread{1.5}
\title{\changefontsizes{20pt} This is My Article Title: 
Which is Fairly Long for A Minimum Working Example}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the font size and baseline skip of the title with `\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont`. For example `\fontsize{20pt}{17pt}\selectfont`

Answer (score 1):

Is this only for the title page? If so, try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\title{\changefontsizes{20pt} This Is My Article Title: 
Which Is Fairly Long for a Minimum Working Example}

\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{spacing}{1}
        \maketitle
    \end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Also, is there a reason why you are using `scrextend` instead of the equivalent KOMA-Script class (i.e., `scrartcl` instead of `article`) in the first place?